# No indication of activated conda environment in terminal

Tags: command-line, anaconda

### Problem

I have a local conda environment in a folder, but when I activate it, I get no indication of having done so. I know that it is activated because if I, as an example, try to remove it, it will tell me I can't remove the current environment. See the screenshot below:

[image]

This is from inside the VSCode terminal, but the same thing happens in a regular terminal window as well. I am looking for there to be a `(env-name)` at the beginning of each line. This problem occurs with any environment I activate.

### Specs

I am running conda 4.8.3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this help you?  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is most likely that you have ps1 value set to False, which enables prompt change with change of conda environment.

To check run from your ubuntu terminal:

`$ conda config --show | grep changeps1`

And set it to True using:

`$ conda config --set changeps1 True`

After this, you should see the currently activated conda environment name at the beginning of each prompt.
PS - You may have to close and reopen the terminal for this to take effect.

Comment: I set `changeps1` to `True`, but now I get an error anytime I try to activate any of my environments. Here are the details: https://bit.ly/3fNSBz1

Comment: Okay, I checked your output of `conda config --show`. Problem seems to be with your`env_prompt` variable which is set to ({flask}), and I think it is invalid . I cross-checked with mine and it's set to ({default_env}). You can do the same by `conda config --set env_prompt '({default_env})' ` or use some other value by referring [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works!